# what is the difference between sendDataMessage and sendTextMessage in android

Tags: android

I mean the only difference is of the port parameter. Does this have any relation between CDMA and GSM phone ?. I have this query because when i try to send a SMS from CDMA without port it goes well but using port my app gets crash. By looking at the logs it shows me

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1253)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1235)
at com.android.internal.telephony.ISms$Stub$Proxy.sendData(ISms.java:558)
at android.telephony.SmsManager.sendDataMessage(SmsManager.java:524)
```

is this a CDMA issue? Because i have the sprint htc phone and i am using it as a roaming in india that may be the case i guess.

here is the API which i use to send sms from CDMA`smsMgr.sendDataMessage(receiverPhoneNumber, null, (short)1001, message.getBytes(), sentPendingIntent, deliveredPendingIntent);`

But from this API it just works fine for both CDMA and GSM `smsMgr.sendTextMessage(receiverPhoneNumber, null, message, sentPendingIntent, deliveredPendingIntent);`

So again what is the diff between sendDataMessage and sendTextMessage?
I have read the documention for these methods but for my scenario it doesn't gets fit properly

Help Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html), it seems like CDMA and GSM shouldn't be an issue provided you aren't using the deprecated `SmsManager` and are instead using the version available from API 4 up (`android.telephony.SmsManager`).

> This class is deprecated. Replaced by android.telephony.SmsManager
>   that supports both GSM and CDMA.

As to the difference between the data message and text message, I believe that the data message includes things like picture texts whereas `sendTextMessage` is pure text. From the error message you provide it sounds like something might have been instantiated incorrectly (leaving a null value somewhere) before the `sendDataMessage` call - can you provide that code and a Logcat of the values `receiverPhoneNumber, null, (short)1001, message.getBytes(), sentPendingIntent, deliveredPendingIntent`?